# Last Not Null Values Power Bi

Tags: dax

I have this table :

| Date | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 20/05/2023 | 400 |
| 27/10/2023 | 500 |

and I have a slicer that I can slice the data by year/quarter/date
My goal is when I select for example the first quarter of 2023 I should see 400 and when i select the first quarter of 2024 or the all year, I will see the 500.
If I select the third quarter of 2023 or Month 9 in 2023 I will see 400.
I slice the data by dim_date table and the sales in a fact table.
Thank you.

I tried a lot of DAX formulas but with no succes.

Comment: What have you tried so far. What did and did not work?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to capture the last (or max) date that is selected/filtered. Then to remove that filter on Sales and add a conditional.

```
Latest Sales = 
  var dLast = LASTDATE('dim_date'[Date])
  RETURN CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANK('fact_sales'[Sales], 1), REMOVEFILTERS(dim_date[Date]), 'fact_sales'[Date] <= dLast)
```

```
Latest Sales v2 = 
  var dLast = LASTDATE('dim_date'[Date])
  RETURN CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANK('fact_sales'[Sales], 1), ALL('fact_sales'[Sales]), 'fact_sales'[Date] <= dLast)
```

Comment: thank you!
it works but for my actual table I need to sum the values, its not only the last non blank, so when I implement the condition 'fact_sales'[Date] <= dLast it will sum duplicates and I need it to sum only the values that equals to the latest date.

Comment: Try the v2 measure above.

Comment: So v2 above worked for your first ask? Please update your question to include part 2 of your ask as I don't fully understand your last comment. You want to sum all up to and including the selected sliced date? And what do you mean about duplicates?